Do elementary row operations change the rank of a matrix' adjugate?
It is known in linear algebra that for an $n\times n$ square matrix $A$:

$\operatorname{rank} = n $ if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A) = n$.
If $\operatorname{rank}A = n-1 $, then $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A) = 1$.
If $\operatorname{rank}A \le n-2$, then $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}A) = 0$.

This led me to conjecture that conducting elementary row operations on a matrix does not change the rank of its adjugate, so we can deduce the results above just by looking at the row-reduced echelon form of $A$. However, apparently this is not true. Are there any counterexamples?

"Apparently this is not true" -- where does this appear? Surely a source for this claim would be a starting point for a source for a proof of the claim, which would, in its simplest form, be a counterexample.

Hint: Note that the elementary row operations don’t change the rank of a matrix.

If you mean to perform elementary row operations on $A$, then the rank of the adjugate of $A$ indeed does not change. Note that

the adjugate matrix of any elementary matrix is invertible, because every elementary matrix is invertible,
in general, $\operatorname{adj}(XY)=\operatorname{adj}(Y)\operatorname{adj}(X)$.

Now, if $P$ is an elementary matrix, then $\operatorname{adj}(P)$ is invertible and hence
$$
\operatorname{rank}\operatorname{adj}(PA)
=\operatorname{rank}\left(\operatorname{adj}(A)\operatorname{adj}(P)\right)
=\operatorname{rank}\operatorname{adj}(A).
$$

Yes I meant elementary row operations. Question corrected.

I'm not sure how well-known your fact 2. is.

@TedShifrin Probably not quite well-known, especially when adjugate is an under-taught topic in most introductory texts or courses.

Agreed. I never taught it myself in any undergraduate course, although I certainly covered its appearance in the formula for $A^{-1}$ without naming it. To me the formula is a consequence of exterior algebra.
